# What is the difference between DRM and DRI on Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, gpu

I have been reading about GPU support in the linux kernel and keep on getting confused with the DRM and DRI acronyms.

This is what i have pieced together.

DRI was first created to work exclusively with X window system. The Kernel component of DRI was DRM, with additional userspace libraries /applications to interact with the DRM.

However, Other userspace frameworks like wayland and OpenGl found the DRM useful and have implemented their own "Infrastructure" around it (DRM)

Are my assumptions right ?